# Banco de dados não recebe as querys pelo script php apesar dele funcionar

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Galera to com um problema em receber o formulário no banco de dados, parece que apesar do script estar correto ele simplesmente o ignora, to usando o xampp, tentei pelo cloud9 também e a mesma coisa acontece.

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$name = $sbname = $sex = $age = $nasc = $email = $site = "";

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){

$name = $_POST['form_nm'];
$sbname = $_POST['form_sobnm'];
$sex = $_POST['form_sex'];
$age = $_POST['form_age'];
$nasc = $_POST['form_nasc'];
$email = $_POST['form_email'];
$site = $_POST['form_site'];

$query = "INSERT INTO pessoas(nome, sobrenome, sexo, idade, nascimento, 
email, website) VALUES ($name, $sbname, $sex, $age, $nasc, $email, $site)";
mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
header('location:../index.php');
?>
```

o arquivo connection :

```
    <?php

    $data = parse_ini_file("config.ini");

    $link = mysqli_connect($data['host'], $data['username'], 
    $data['password'], $data['database']);

    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        die("Unable to connect to database! Error: " . 
    mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    ?>
```

e o config.ini :

```
    [SERVER_DATA]

    host = 'localhost';
    username = 'root';
    password = '';
    database = 'atividade_ecomp';
```

Tá tudo correto, já revisei diversas vezes, o banco de dados, a tabela e as colunas estão com os nomes corretos, estou usando o phpMyAdmin mas mesmo após o envio do formulário o banco de dados não adiciona as informações.

Comment: Aparenta ter uma quebra de linha em `$query` e em `$link` deve remove-los.

Comment: Pior que não tem, ao colar pra cá que ficou assim, no sublime tá normal.

Comment: O botão de enviar esta com o nome certo ? `enviar` ?

Comment: Duas coisas, (1) imprima $query e veja o resultado, pelo visto estão faltando os apóstrofos/aspas para separar as strings em *values* e (2) faça algo como `if ( mysql_connect(...) ){ echo "Ok" } else { echo "Erro!" }` para verificar se a operação foi realmente bem sucedida.

Comment: Uma terceira coisa, vale a pena ler sobre como se conectar de forma segura ao banco de dados em PHP, a forma como você está fazendo está para ser removida da linguagem. -- http://br.phptherightway.com/#banco_de_dados

Comment: Se não mostra nenhum erro na tela o mais provável é que nem esteja entrando no  `if`, coloque vários `echo` para ver por onde o fluxo do programa está indo e os valores das variáveis e do comando sql

Comment: faz um teste de erro `if (mysqli_query($link, $query)){echo "sucesso";} else {echo "Erro: " . $query. "<br>" . mysqli_error($link}`

Comment: Realmente o erro era a falta dos apostrofas nos values, muito obrigado!!